# Delete an item from an asp:Repeater using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How do I delete an item from a asp:Repeater? At the moment I have the following code for the repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="uxRolesList" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>                       
        <div id="<%# GetRolesDivId() %>">
            <asp:TextBox ID="uxTxtBoxRole" runat="server" rows="5" columns="100" Text='<%# Container.DataItem %>' TextMode="multiline" MaxLength="2000"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="uxRemoveRoleBtn" Style="vertical-align:top;" CssClass="remove-roles-btn" runat="server" Text="X" />
            <br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="uxValTxtBoxRole" ControlToValidate="uxTxtBoxRole" ErrorMessage="Please complete this role requirement"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br /><br />
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Which should output something like this:

```
<div id="roles-1">
    <textarea name="ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl01$uxTxtBoxRole" rows="5" cols="100" id="ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl01_uxTxtBoxRole">Quick test</textarea>                          <input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl01$uxRemoveRoleBtn" value="X" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$mainContent$uxRolesList$ctl01$uxRemoveRoleBtn&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl01_uxRemoveRoleBtn" class="remove-roles-btn" style="vertical-align:top;" />
    <br />
    <span id="ctl00_mainContent_uxRolesList_ctl01_uxValTxtBoxRole" class="error" style="color:#891F11;display:none;">Please complete this role requirement</span>
    <br /><br />
</div>
```

And I'm using the following jQuery to 'delete' the item when the delete button is clicked:

```
$("#roles-" + roleIdNumber).remove();
e.preventDefault();
rolesCounter--;
```

Where `roleIdNumber` is 1 in this case.

But when I submit the form, the item still appears - can anyone help me with what is happening?

Comment: if you have reposted the form then it will be data bound again, so if the record still exists it will be regenrated

Comment: Could you paste full aspx and javascript section?

Comment: put yr code on document ready function..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest replacing:

```
<div id="<%# GetRolesDivId() %>">
```

with:

```
<div id="<%# GetRolesDivId() %>" class="div_row">
```

and this line:

```
<asp:Button ID="uxRemoveRoleBtn" Style="vertical-align:top;" CssClass="remove-roles-btn" runat="server" Text="X" />
```

with:

```
<input type="button" style="vertical-align:top;" value="X" class="remove-roles-btn" onclick="$(this).parents('.div_row').remove();rolesCounter--;" />
```

and remove all the js code you shared here.

hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably not working because the repeater items are added to the DOM after the Document.Ready function call has finished executing.

If your repeater fetches data after the page load is complete, then consider using [Jquery's on() method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or the [delegate method](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).